Installing plank laminate over a waterproof vinyl floating floor
Do I need to take up the existing flooring. The product is a good quality floor and because it's waterproof, would it make a good underlayment. The flooring is over a wood floor, not on slab.

Usually the only flooring needing to removed for that type of flooring is carpet.
If water proof type is needed for the room type, you want to keep with water proof.
The only problem is the raising of the floor.  A half inch rise from the other room/hall can be a bother to some people.
